# Parsing a CSV file and having trouble parsing the date

Tags: python, csv

I'm using `dateutil.parser.parse(date)` which works fine for individual dates but the problem is that if I have two days (i.e.  `20/04/2032` and `05/04/1991`) then it will read it as April 20th and May 4th, respectively.

I'll be reading in columns which are form consistent but I won't know the form of the column ahead of time as I wish to support CSVs from multiple sources.

Say I have a list like (although in reality they could be much bigger):

1. `["01/02/2012", "01/04/2012", "01/05/2012", "01/05/2012", "01/25/2012"]`
2. `["01022012", "01042012", "01052012", "01052012", "01252012"]`
3. `["01/2nd/2012", etc...]`

By eyeing the list i can see that the `01` is the month for sure but I need this check to be automatic. I can't just check for a number greater than `12` because it could catch the year sub-string by accident.

The data I need to extract from this is whether the day comes before or after the month. So that when I go back later and parse the string again, I know what to grab.

I can't seem to come up with a way to do this check in a clean and efficient way.

Comment: I've been trying to work something out but I can't just search for something specific because the date could be entirely text. The date may not even have a separator in it and a date like 122712 could falsly indicate the day comes both before and after the month.

Comment: how do you want to parse 05/04/1991? if you didn't give a format, there're two ways of parsing - as april 05 or may 04. How do you want to parse 010101? You have to define an input format for dates or you have to define your priority rules

Comment: The problem is that I need uniform parsing but I don't know the format of the file I'm going to encounter. A file may be MMDDYYYY or DDMMYYY or any of the types above. Any number of them can be amgibious so I have to figure out what the format is before I parse it (or on the fly if there is a simple way to check as I go). The problem is that I'm not sure how to go from a datetime object to 'this is how its displayed'.

Comment: Are all of the dates in your column guaranteed to have the _same_ format?  If so you have some hope (if a 2-digit position has a value > 12 -> it is the day position), if every row can be a different format, you are hosed.

Comment: It's fair to assume the columns are consistent but it may not be an integer (i.e. 'twenty fifth' or '25th') so I'm not sure how to check for this.

Comment: I think I made it clearer.

Comment: Yeah, now it's clear. Reopened! I have not experience with Python at all but does it support regular expressions? Seems like case for regex.

Comment: Are you saying that if _x_ number of dates in a given list fall into a pattern, that is the assumed pattern for the rest of the list? This is the only way I can surmise you arrived at your conclusion (by looking at `01252012`) and then using that as the "check"?

Comment: Basically users can upload CSV files. It's fair to assume (and treat) the data as consistent. Inconsistent data is a bit far fetched to support. But I would ideally like to support many types of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# date is a string from the csv file.  
 if len(date) == 8 and all(isdigit(i) for i in date):  
# then it's either the year comes first or last

    date = ["-".join([date[0:4], date[4:6], date[6:8])],
            "-".join([date[0:2], date[2:4], date[4:8])]
           ]
    # only one should be a possible date. if both are and the month
    # combinations don't sort it out then it's too ambigious anyway.

# I'll do something similar for a string of 6 digits. but now I know that all
# strings that are digits only are now seperated.
# I'll also figure out which is the year (or make a reasonable guess and expand
# the number to 8 and make the spaces).

date = date.lower() # or an equivalent if it screws with symbols and numbers

for month in full_length_month_list:
  if month in date:
        # I know I can parse this.

for month in three_letter_month_list:
    if month in date:
        # I know I can parse this.

month_days = {'first':01, 'second':02, 'third':03, ... ,'thirty first': 31}
for string, number in month_days:
    date.replace(string,number)

for shorthand in ['st','nd','rd','th']:
    date.replace(shorthand, '')

date.replace('the','')

# Then I use a regex matcher to get 3 sets of digits: The longest set is the 
# year. The shortest two sets are either date or month. I can get the order
# based on the matcher. Then I can figure out by looping through if there is
# ever a date greater than 12. If so I know the order. I can also possibly
# track the replacements maybe. So that if jan/january was in the original
# string I already know anyway.
```

This is a potential roadmap I've come up with that seems reasonable enough? Any major flaws or immediate drawbacks? I could use some help turning this into something relatively robust given it's purpose is to used on unknown strings.

Then I could keep a set for year, month and day with {0,1,2} and just return which weren't possible positions for a given element (year, month, day) and use set subtractions. If any set reaches {} then it cannot be read. If any set has more than 1 element at the end I make a local choice on date/month based on precedence (any maybe assume the lower variance is the month?). And if there's only one combination I store that for when the dates are read in later and just pass that to the reader.

Comment: This has the disadvantage of not using the parser but the advantage of allowing me to know which position the various elements are in. I'm not sure how reasonably well covered I am in this approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the format, you cannot parse. Its really that simple. Both these (`5/4/91` and `5/4/1991`) will pass any check that will check for valid dates; but only you can know if its 4th of May or 5th of April, and you can only know that if you know what was the *intended* format.

In the end the best you can hope for is a list of valid parsable dates, a list of unparsed (but might be valid) dates.  Then you have to manually go through both to see if the dates make sense.

To get these lists:

```
try:
    maybe_valid.append(dateutil.parser.parse(some_date))
except ValueError:
    probably_invalid.append(some_date)
```

Comment: I'm not too concerned about overly ambiguous cases i.e. every date is ambiguous in the column. But lets say I have 1000 dates and 999 are ambiguous but one clearly has the date first. How can I, in a clean and efficient way, find that the order is not ambiguous (and what it is)?

Comment: What do you mean "has the date first"?

Comment: sorry I meant 'day' first. as in day before month.

Comment: The naive check would be to see if the first two digits are > 12.

Comment: Agree with Burhan, you have to know it's format. whatever it is DD/MM/YYYY or MM-DD-YY, YOU HAVE TO KNOW THAT. If that uses more different formats (all known), there's no one line solution, probably will take some workaround to make it work.

Comment: Exactly, what I'm looking for is a reasonable workaround that at least covers enough cases to be passable.